# Should I uncomment out the code referring to unhide.rb (as I am using unhide.rb)?

Tags: configuration, rkhunter

I am using `rkhunter 1.4.2`, on Ubuntu 14.10, and I am also using the suggested package `unhide.rb` with it, so should I uncomment out this setting referring to it in the `rkhunter.conf` file?:

```
#SCRIPTWHITELIST=/usr/bin/unhide.rb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should uncomment that line.  This will allow `rkhunter` to run `unhide.rb` without you having to run it manually!  (but still allowing you to run it manually if you want)

Low quality reviewers: Some answers have complex questions and simple answers…

Comment: Indeed, very simple. =)